# C# Linq to XML Checking If Directory Exists

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have the following XML file layout:

```html
<TopNode>
  <AppRun Date="26-Jun-17 02:15">
    <Folder Name="Folder1">
      <SubFolder Name="SubFolder1" />
      <SubFolder Name="SubFolder2" />
    </Folder>
    <Folder Name="Folder2">
      <SubFolder Name="SubFolder1" />
      <SubFolder Name="SubFolder2" />
    </Folder>
  </AppRun>
</TopNode>
```

And the following frankencode i've mashed together:

```
        TopNode.Add(new XElement("AppRun",
            new XAttribute("Date", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yy hh:mm")),
            _folderNameArray.Select(x => new XElement("Folder", new XAttribute("Name", x),
                Directory.GetDirectories(Path.Combine(_sourceDirectory, x), "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).
                                             Select(y => new XElement("SubFolder", new XAttribute("Name", Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(y))))))));
```

So I have the folder element names in an array as they stay constant; However, the folders may not always be there. So when the application tries to do the directories, it'll throw a DirectoryNotFound exception. I'd like to keep an empty folder element in the xml even if the directory doesn't exist.

Can someone point me in the right direction to edit this block of code to check the directory exists before trying to probe it.

Comment: Wrap Directory.GetDirectories() in your own method and call that instead, then you can make it return whatever you like if a Directory.Exists() test fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get all the SubFolders in you folders list

```
var mainFolder = "C:\\";
            var folders = new []{ "Test" , "ABCFG" };

            var data = new XElement("AppRun", 
                       from folderName in folders
                       let path = Path.Combine(mainFolder,folderName)
                       select new XElement("Folder", 
                           new XAttribute("Name",folderName), 
                           Directory.Exists(path) ? from subDir in  Directory.GetDirectories(path, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                                                    select new XElement("SubFolder",new XAttribute("Name", Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(subDir))): null));

            Console.WriteLine(data.ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks mate! Had to tweak it a bit for my environment, but works as advertised! Thanks for your time ;-)